# Trying to pull back ONLY foreign script in a large file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arabic, file-writing

I have a very large file with intermingled English and foreign language material (mostly Arabic script and some other languages). I'm not concerned with detecting or identifying the language. I'm new to Python and struggling to write this code. I want my code to read the .txt file, ignore anything in English/Latin/ascii-encodable characters, and print just the foreign language material to a new .txt file.

So far, I have:

```
sourceDoc = open("test_doc.txt", 'r')
destDoc = open("test_doc_dest.txt", 'w')
for line in sourceDoc:
    try:
        line.isascii()
    except:
        destDoc.write(line)
sourceDoc.close()
destDoc.close()
```

One thing I know is probably wrong with my code is that I'm asking it to find foreign language material and write the whole line to the new file. I really just want to write the foreign language material to the new file and discard the rest of the line if it's in English/Latin characters.

I keep getting a traceback for line 3 in the code and for line 23 in the source document, which is where the first instance of foreign language material appears.

Comment: Please include the actual traceback and a computer-readable representation of the problematic input. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: `line.isascii()` returns `True` or `False`, but does not raise an exception for input which isn't pure ASCII. Realistically, many passages of English text will also include accented characters, curly quotes, non-breaking spaces etc which are not pure ASCII.

Comment: What is the encoding of the input file? Most sane systems use UTF-8, but on Windows you should expect some godforsaken legacy 8-bit encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use a regex pattern matching non-Latin characters (this would also included characters with a script value of `Common` and `Inherited`, i.e. keep punctuation and whitespace.

To use Unicode POSIX or Perl style notation, I need to use the **regex** module rather than **re** module.

Install module:  `pip install -U regex`.

Both **re** and **regex** have a method `re.fullmatch` or `regex.fullmatch` which only returns a match if the whole string matches the pattern.

The code below can be written different ways, the key points are 1) using regex module instead or re; and 2) match non-Latin text using `\P{Latin}`.

Both `re.fullmatch(r'\P{Latin}+', line)` or `re.match(r'^\P{Latin}+$', line)` would be appropriate. Everything else is fluid, and code as it suits you.

```py
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile(r'\P{Latin}+')
with open("multi-lang.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines_subset = [line for line in lines if bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, line))]
with open("multi-lang-out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as o:
    o.write('\n'.join(lines_subset))
```

If you want to only exclude pure ASCII lines (on the potentially mistaken assumption that only English is ASCII only) and keep everything else, search and match any lines containing non-ASCII characters:

```py
p = r'[\P{Basic Latin}]'   # or r'[^[:ASCII:]]'
with open("multi-lang.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines_subset = [line for line in lines if bool(re.search(p, line))]
with open("multi-lang-out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as o:
    o.write('\n'.join(lines_subset))
```